# topic classification using k-gram index

Tags: python, nlp, data-mining, information-retrieval

I have a set of topics each described with a list of keywords. `{Sports:['Ronaldo Messi Zidane','Football Baseball', 'Barcelona Real']...}`

The task is to classify a particular document. The classification can be also multi-label. A document can belong to topic1,topic2 etc. I don't have enough data thus can't approach the problem using machine learning. Because I want to retrieve highly precise documents I approached the problem using `k-gram` index.

I treat a given set of topic keywords as queries and built a `k-gram` index around it. So I have all the keys as character bigrams and the values as terms which contain the bigram. These terms are terms present in the document that I want to classify. After traversing the postings list for every keyword of a topic I get a set of candidate terms and their corresponding jaccard similarity score.

1. Within a topic How do I combine jaccard score of all candidate terms ?
2. Within all topics how do I decide which topic this document belongs to ?
3. Do you think this approach can give me results with high precision ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a multi-class multi-label classification problem. Since the questioner is comfortable using a detailed lexical approach. This article [here](https://www.listendata.com/2018/05/sentiment-analysis-using-python.html) will help in building a pragmatic solution.